# windows 10 equivalent to windows 7 "end process"

Tags: windows-10, process, task-manager

In windows 7, when I program hangs, I call up the task list. If I do "end task" it will ask if I want to "Wait for the program to close", or "End now". Whichever option I choose, it seems to just hang indefinitely while "waiting for the program to close" (I get an infinite green progressbar). So, I always right click the task in the task list, select "Go To Process" which brings me to the associated process in the process list tab, and choose "End Process" which, 100% of the time, kills the program instantly, which is exactly what I want.

**EDIT** *For clarification:*

---

According to this:
[What advantages does Ending Task have over Ending Process?](https://superuser.com/questions/383886/what-advantages-does-ending-task-have-over-ending-process)

End Task is skin to just clicking the "Close" button on a window, whereas "End Process" is more akin to the system truly terminating the application.

Emphasis added by me:

> For programs having at least one window, **End Task does the same as
>   clicking the X "Close" button** – it sends the WM_CLOSE message to that
>   window, asking it nicely to close. (For console windows, the
>   equivalent is CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT.) The program can prompt the user to
>   save changes, or do various cleanup tasks. If the process complies,
>   Task Manager waits a few seconds and proceeds with terminating the
>   process if it is still running.
>
> **If the process is frozen or otherwise not handling window messages it
>   receives, then, of course, neither End Task nor the Close button can
>   work.** In those cases, Windows will usually ask you to end the program
>   forcefully, but only after giving the program sufficient time to
>   respond.
>
> **Meanwhile, the End Process button does not concern itself with tasks
>   or windows – it calls the TerminateProcess() function and Windows
>   destroys the process immediately, without notifying it or giving it
>   any chance to clean up.**

---

In windows 10, even though there is a "Process List" when I am in the task manager, the only options I have to kill a program are "End Task". **Is there any way to get Win7's "End Process" functionality under Windows 10?** Preferably without a 3rd party utility, but a 3rd party utility is fine if it is absolutely not possible under Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 10, the Details tab is the new processes tab.
Try right-clicking the process that is hanging and select "Go to Details."
From there you should see "End Task" and the other usual options. As Daniel B has mentioned, Ending task in the details window is not the same as in the processes window.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This change has been there since Windows 8, btw. And although the button there is also called “End Task” (at least on 8.1), it most definitely does not send any `WM_CLOSE` message or the like.

Answer (score -2):

You click on the program u want to close either by using tab and arrow keys or just clicking it with mouse and then you click delete on your keyboard